# How to add textboxs to the dynamically created pictureboxes

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a program which dynamically creates movable pictureboxes when I click on buttons. I need to do something like when I click on the picturebox, this click adds to my dynamically created picturebox a new textbox when I can write descripiton of this picturebox(name,...). This textbox should be able to move with picturebox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            List<PictureBox> pictureboxes = new List<PictureBox>();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void AddPictureBox(string imagePath)
            {
                var pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Name = "picturebox" + pictureboxes.Count;
                pb.Location = new Point(pictureboxes.Count * 100, 100);
                pb.Size = new Size(70, 70);
                pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                this.Controls.Add(pb);

                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
                pb.Refresh();
                pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseDown);
                pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseMove);
                pb.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picMouseUp);

                pictureboxes.Add(pb);

                Invalidate();
            }

            private void router_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddPictureBox(@"D:\\router.jpg");

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            bool drag = false;

            private void picMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                // Get original position of cursor on mousedown
                x = e.X;
                y = e.Y;
                drag = true;
            }

            private void picMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (drag)
                {
                    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
                    // Get new position of picture
                    pb.Top += e.Y - y;
                    pb.Left += e.X - x;
                    pb.BringToFront();

                    Invalidate();
                }
            }

            private void picMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                drag = false;
            }

            private void switch1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\Grafika\switch1.png");

            }

            private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void pc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\pc.jpg");

            }

            private void server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddPictureBox(@"D:\HP ProBook 450\Desktop\server.png");


            }
    }
```

Thanks for any help :).

Comment: Let's take a step back: You try what you descibe to accomplish with the forms designer first. If that works then look into doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `TextBox` to a `PictureBox` in code like this:

```
TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
newTextBox.Parent = yourPictureBox;
// place it e.g. to the left bottom:
newTextBox.Location = new Point(10, yourPictureBox.Height - newTextBox.Height);
```

Note that this will add the `TextBox` to the `Controls` collection of the PB; so it will sit **on top** of the `PictureBox`; so, yes, it will move with the `PictureBox` but it will also hide a part or the PB!

If instead you simply want to group them, add them both to something like a `Panel`, again by setting that as their `Parent`!

Also note that you can't do this in the Designer; `PictureBox` is not really meant to act as a `Container`..

It doesn't matter how the `PictureBox` was created, as long as you have a reference to it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me :). I have one more question. Is it posible to do a button which hides/shows this textbox(or all textboxes)? I can do this when a have one textbox where I can set texbox.visible = false, but in dynamic textboxes i dont. Thanks

Comment: Yes, changing the `Visible` property is not hard if you have a reference. Assuming you have added only one Control to the PictureBox you can toggle it like this: `onePictureBox.Controls[0].Visible = ..` where '..' could be `true`, `false` or `!onePictureBox.Controls[0].Visible` - So to turn them all off you could do `foreach(PictureBox pb in pictureboxes)  pb.Controls[0].Visible = false;`..

Comment: Ok, but when I am in private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) I dont have reference to the picturebox or textbox. When I use sender to the textbox it throws some error.

Comment: Well, if you use the `pictureboxes` that won't happen. If you want to toggle the TB for a __single__ PB, which PB do you mean? If you can tell me, I'm sure we can tell your Button, too.. Its `sender` is the Button itself, so that won't help..

Comment: If you want to, you can show and hide the TB upon clicking (or doubleclicking) on the PB if you code like this: `pb.Click += delegate { pb.Controls[0].Visible ^= true ; };` to the code that creates each PB.. (Assuming eaxch has a TB; if not insert a check for `Controls.Count > 0`

Comment: Ok, I want to toggle all textboxes so I have 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            foreach (PictureBox pb in pictureboxes) pb.Controls[0].Visible = false;
           
        }
but nothning happens. It doesnt hide the textboxes.

Comment: I can't see why. Do use the Debugger and check that all PictureBoxes are still in that List! (I don't know how you add it to the Form..)

Comment: Thank youu very much. It is even better(option with pb.click). It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)